# django extend model user error this field is requiered

Tags: django

This is my first Django project and i'm blocked since 1 month i need help please.
I would like to extend the model user (to add "age" and "sex").
But in my view.py "form.is_valid()" is false and the error is :

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is requiered.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

May be i made a big mistake i watch a lot of tutorials to make this code.
This is my model.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Profil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  # La liaison OneToOne vers le modele User                                      
    Age = models.IntegerField()
    Sexe = models.BooleanField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profil de {0}".format(self.user.username)
```

This is my view.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import Profil

class ProfilForm(ModelForm):
    FirstName = forms.CharField(label='Prenom',max_length=100)
    LastName = forms.CharField(label="Nom",max_length=100)
    MailAdress = forms.EmailField(label="Adresse mail",max_length=100)
    Age = forms.IntegerField(label='Age',min_value=16,max_value=120)
    Sexe = forms.BooleanField(label='Sexe',initial=False)
    UserName = forms.CharField(label='Pseudo',max_length=100)
    Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label="Mot de passe",max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        model = Profil


def SubmitFormulaireInscription(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfilForm(request.POST)
        html = form
        print form.errors
        if form.is_valid():
            FirstName = form.cleaned_data['FirstName']
            LastName = form.cleaned_data['LastName']
            MailAdress = form.cleaned_data['MailAdress']
            Age = form.cleaned_data['Age']
            Sexe = form.cleaned_data['Sexe']
            UserName = form.cleaned_data['UserName']
            Password = form.cleaned_data['Password']

            user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=FirstName,last_name=LastName,email=MailAdress,username=UserName,\
password=Password,Age=Age,Sexe=Sexe)
            user.save()

            html = "<html><body>merci mon ami ton first name = {!s} et ton last name = {!s} et ton email = {!s} et ton \
pseudo = {!s} et ton mot de passe = {!s} et ton age = {!s}  </html></body>".format(FirstName,LastName,MailAdress,UserNa\
me,Password,Age)

            return HttpResponse(html)
    else:
        form = ProfilForm()

    return render(request, 'inscription.html', { 'form': form, })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProfilForm` is a ModelForm for `Profil` model. But you are trying to use fields from the `User` model.  That can only work if you have used [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

You haven't used model inheritance, you just have a OneToOneField joining two *separate* models.

You need to first decide if you really want separate `User` and `Profil` models (that is valid, but you then need to structure your forms and view around the *two* models).

You may be better off having a single [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) with the `Age` and `Sexe` fields added to it.

Comment: ok thank's, i tried to make it with AbstractUser but i failed.
Do you have an easy example (or tutorial) for beginner like me ?
Wich explain all files (model.py, view.py, inscription.html)?
Thank you very much !!!